# How can I set a user object's manager property with a contact using powershell?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to set a user objects' manager property with a mail-contact. I can find the contact and have tried setting the user object by specifying the name, displayname, identity, and guid, but nothing is working. It's quite easy to do in the AD user object, but not with PowerShell.

Comment: Identity contains what? The manager attribute, ultimately, must contain a distinguishedName. What are you using to attempt to set it? I can think of no less than 5 different ways to set it in PowerShell ranging from ADSI to specific Cmdlet / module implementations.

Comment: I've tried using the distinguished name, but it doesn't work:

PS SB:\> $mgrcontact.distinguishedname
CN=First Last,OU=Company,OU=Contacts,OU=Exchange Resource Objects,DC=Company,DC=com

PS SB:\> $MGR = $mgrcontact.distinguishedname

PS SB:\> set-aduser dmerrill -manager $mgr
set-aduser : Identity info provided in the extended attribute: 'Manager' could not be resolved. Reason: 'Cannot find an 
object with identity: 'CN=First Last,OU=Company,OU=Contacts,OU=Exchange Resource Objects,DC=Company,DC=com' 
under: 'DC=Company,DC=com'.'.